# xmlValue with xpathSApply concatenates all leaf values into one character

Tags: xml, r, xml-parsing

I am parsing data from an xml file structure that looks like this:

```
<Filegram Status="Idle" Version="3.0.0.12">
<CXDVideo>
<ArrayOfDouble xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<double>0.074345000088214874</double>
<double>0.081780999898910522</double>
<double>0.089218996465206146</double>
<double>0.0966539978981018</double>
<double>0.10408999770879746</double>
<double>0.1115259975194931</double>
<double>0.11896199733018875</double>
</ArrayOfDouble>
</CXDVideo>
</Filegram>
```

After importing the xml file with `doc1 <- xmlParse()`, I try to extract the numbers using this command:

```
xpathSApply(doc1, "//Video/ArrayOfDouble", xmlValue)
```

I obtain all values as a single character:

```
[[1]]
[1] "00.00623949430882930760.0132457073777914050.0202680919319391250.0306097287684679030.0346436910331249240.0412975363433361050.0483214072883129120.0553476661443710330.0623622909188270570.0693683102726936340.0763849914073944090.083491444587707520.0904
```

With xmlToDataFrame or xmlToList parses this section just fine but very slowly. I was hoping to speed up the data extraction process using xpathSApply, just can't get it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you want to grab the xmlValue for each of the "double" nodes, not the entire "ArrayOfDouble" xml fragment. Try

```
as.numeric(xpathSApply(doc1, "//Video/ArrayOfDouble/double", xmlValue) )
```

which will also convert the character values to numeric values.

Comment: I needed to fix the XML errors (tag mismatch and premature end of data) before the XMLParse call succeeded.

Comment: I had shortened the original XML file (3MB) to the relevant part - and forgot to add/edit the tags. Fixed now.